# Help Needed! My vehicle (2015 Nissan Sentra) is not starting after Brake Job. - DIY

Tags: battery, brakes, starting, nissan, sentra

After doing brake job, both front Disk and rear drum, I have tried starting the vehicle but it's not starting. haven't faced this issue previously don't know what's wrong. It seems completely weird. We haven't touched anything in the front hood expect the master cylinder.

But before lowering the jack, when the car was on the jack stands, we tried starting the car. At that time, it started fine without any issue. but after we lowered the and tried to start it wasn't starting. dash lights glow up, small crank (sound) from the front and then nothing. Though battery issues (Not sure whether its battery or not) Inside the car console works, but console restarts while I am trying to start the car. fan under ac vents works, head light works

I don't know what went wrong. request your help.

Is this a battery issue? does using jump started helps? or something else

Comment: Have you measured the voltage at the battery?

Comment: No. I don't know how to do that. recently (3 months ago) got the car, now started doing its maintenance.  
Can you share any DIY video for that? How much should the battery voltage be?

Comment: Sometimes a door, trunk is accidentally left open, or ignition switch is left on while doing repairs. This will cause the battery to drain over time. You should have 12.2 - 12.6 volts at the battery with a volt meter. If not, have the battery recharged.

Comment: Check for blown fuses. If all are fine, then answer two questions. 
1-With a fully charged battery or boost from another battery, does the engine crank, turnover with starter sounds or not? Battery cables and their connections must be free of corrosion and connected securely. No starter sounds points to; battery, battery cables, their connections, starter.
2-If the starter runs and turns over the engine, but the engine doesn't fire up, this may be one of three issues; no spark, no fuel (remove spark plugs to examine them for fuel) or both, pointing to a dead crank position sensor.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have run down your battery. You hear a click but there's no crank and the dash lights go out when you try and start, that's a classic low voltage situation. Either your battery is old and won't hold a charge, or it was drained while you were working on the car. To reiterate the good information in the comments trunk, hood or passenger compartments lights are the most common culprits. Or, if you were working on the car for a long time, like weeks, it could be the battery just losing charge over time.

It takes a lot of energy to start a car, and you need to run your car after starting it to replace that energy. You started your car while it was on jacks, then turned it off right away leaving your battery depleted.

The solution is simple: jump the car, then drive the car to charge the battery back up. I'd run it for at least 20 minutes, maybe longer as the battery was flat. You could also buy a battery charger and use that to charge the battery, which will take longer.

As for how to avoid that in the future the simplest way is to disconnect the battery when you work on the car, first the negative and then the positive terminal. If the battery isn't connected it can't be drained. If you are going to work on your car for more than a week at a time you should consider buying a trickle charger as your battery will naturally run down even if it's not connected.

A multimeter would be a very good purchase, it's a piece of test equipment that you can use to read AC/DC voltage, amps, resistance and other measurements which can help you diagnose common problems in your car. Ordinarily I suggest buying quality equipment, but the difference in price between cheap and known brands is huge, so unless you are made of cash an inexpensive one is the way to go. I'm amazed with what you can get for $10 in the multimeter space.

To test your battery you would turn your multimeter to DC volts, usually a symbol which is a V with parallel lines, then touch the probes to the battery terminals at the same time. The number that goes on the multimeter screen is your battery voltage. A charged battery would be at least 12.5 volts, yours is probably far lower than that. If your battery is that or higher but you are still having trouble starting then you have a different problem.

Comment: Good, solid answer ... +1

Comment: FYI: Only test the volts.  If you value your multimeter do *not* test the amperage.  Most multimeters are designed to test amps way less than 100.  Most car batteries are in the 500 to 900 amp range.  Even dead car batteries can be enough to blow the fuse or damage the multimeter more thoroughly.